# The Right Way to Edit Single Attributes Inside Core Data using a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application which consists of a table view and a plus button for users to modally go to another view controller, add in some text into the text fields and to save it.

Saving it in the back-end means saving to Core Data which then displays that to the table view controller using NSFetchedResultsController.

The model is:

Transaction Entity
Date Entity
Occasion Entity
Person Entity

The Transaction Entity has a relationship to the other entities, so Person's NAME attribute would be whoFrom.name.

Everything works well with the adding new entries, but I'm stuck when it comes to editing. I click on a cell and through prepareForSegue, the information in the view controller get's set. The name text field has the entered name, and the event text field has the entered name.

I want to be able to edit this cleanly.

So if the user changes the name text field from Jack to Bill, I want it to change for THIS cell only, without changing every jack to bill.

So the following logic should be adhered to:

- Change name from Jack to Bill

  - If Bill exists, return it and add this transaction to Bill's transactions
  - if Bill does not exist, create it.
  - If Jack only had one transaction and I rename Jack to Bill, ensure to remove "Jack" from Core Data.

I have code to already to 1 and 2 when it comes to saving a new entry.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
Transaction *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Person *enteredPerson = (Person *)[Person personWithName:self.nameTextField.text inManagedObjectContext:context];
transaction.whoBy = enteredPerson;
```

The personWithName is a category on the Person NSManagedObjectSubclass:

```
+ (Person *)personWithName:(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Person *person = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the name of the person already exists
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *people = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!people)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else if (![people count])
    {
        // If the person count is 0 then let's create it
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        person.name = name;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the object exists, just return the last object .
        person = [people lastObject];
    }
    return person; 
}
```

I have been reading tutorials and thinking about how to do this in the "Save" method of my editing view controller, or detail view controller as it's commonly called but I just cannot figure out how to get this working.

With editing, I don't want to create a new transaction, I want to just get the information for THAT transaction, change the name or event and save it again. So I cannot imagine I'd put insertNewObject into the save method of the DetailViewController.

Do I assign a newName and an oldName, do I update transaction.whoBy, etc?

I'm really lost with this one so any push in the right direction would be immensely helpful; I know I'm close because my save method above for adding new entries already does successfully the logic of returning a user if he exists or creating one if he does not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. Your person instance either exists or it doesn't. If it does, present a list to the user where he can choose the person to edit. If it is a new person, allow the user to explicitly create a new person.

If the user tries to create a new person with a name that already exists, ask the user what to do.

From the view controller perspective it is easy. You can use the same controller for editing and creating. Just give it a `@property` of type `Person` and simply change the attributes, such as the name. If it is an edit assign the selected person, if not create one and assign it. If it is a new one and the user cancels, delete the object.

Comment: Thanks @Mundi - that makes a lot of sense and I've basically got that working - I'm not sure if this is another question (if it is ,i'll happily ask it) but I have a tab based entirely on "Person" which displays just the names.. when I edit the cell from the first table view (as per the question), it works well, but it doesn't remove the old username if it only had one entry.. so example.. John has one entry.. I rename John to Bill and it creates Bill fine with all of the information there, but it also keeps John.. at this stage, John should now be deleted.. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: or perhaps deleted is not the right word.. but with John not having any transactions, he shouldn't appear in the list of Names..

Comment: Names controller should implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate with the boilerplate callback implementations. John will then become Bill "automatically".